# How to look up date from a URL with parameters?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, dspace, apache-cocoon

I am using XSLT to look up data in an external document, which is an XML file from a DSpace URL ([link](http://papaya.testes.iphan.gov.br/xmlui/search-filter?field=author&rpp=100000&XML)). But I cannot use an URL with parameters in document().

This is my code:

```
<xsl:param name="myurl">
  <xsl:text>cocoon://search-filter?field=author&amp;rpp=100000&amp;XML</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:value-of select="document($myurl)//dri:metadata[@element='contextPath'][not(@qualifier)]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="document($myurl)//metadata[@element='contextPath'][not(@qualifier)]"/>
```

The log file shows this:

```
WARN  org.apache.cocoon.components.xslt.TraxErrorListener  - Can not load requested doc: unknown protocol: cocoon at file:///dados-teste/webapps/xmlui/themes/Papaya/lib/xsl/papaya/navigation.xsl:245:78
```

If I use a different URL (without parameters), it does work! For example:

```
<xsl:param name="myurl">
  <xsl:text>cocoon://metadata/handle/123456789/1261/mets.xml</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need it to be the cocoon protocol? Does it work if you switch to `http`?

Comment: Thanks! This answer did worked for me!
(I was using cocoon protocol, because I saw it in someone else's code)

Answer (score 0):

I added this declaration to my stylesheet and it is not failing for me.  Have you set the rpp too high for your server to process?

Comment: I tried a lower rpp value (100), but I didn´t work anyway. And the server can process higher rpp values.The schweerelos' answer worked for me! Thanks for the response.